# Azure Automation Job runs fine manually but fails when triggered by webhook

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, webhooks

I've got an Automation Account in Azure that runs a Powershell runbook.
It runs perfectly fine when I trigger it via the portal, manually specifying the inputs
[image: Successful run]

I've created a webhook with the same input settings. I call it from CURL like

`curl -d '' https://800b2bec-b1ae-4fa1-ba30-8c7d32096828.webhook.ae.azure-automation.net/webhooks?[redactedtoken]`

The webhook shows as triggered successfully in the portal, however the job fails with no visible error.

[image: Failed run]

There is no output, even though the first line in my powershell function is `Write-Output "Hello"`

There are no exception messages, no logs at all.

Any idea how I might get more information as to what might be going wrong?

I've updated the Az modules and enabled verbose logging in the runbook.

Full source below, if it helps.

```
Param(
 [string]$resourceGroup,
 [string]$VMName,
 [string]$method,
 [string]$UAMI 
)
Write-Output "Hello"
$automationAccount = "AlsAutomation"

# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null

# Connect using a Managed Service Identity
try {
        $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
    }
catch{
        Write-Output "There is no system-assigned user identity. Aborting."; 
        exit
    }

# set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription `
    -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

if ($method -eq "SA")
    {
        Write-Output "Using system-assigned managed identity"
    }
elseif ($method -eq "UA")
    {
        Write-Output "Using user-assigned managed identity"

        # Connects using the Managed Service Identity of the named user-assigned managed identity
        $identity = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
            -Name $UAMI -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

        # validates assignment only, not perms
        if ((Get-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
                -Name $automationAccount `
                -DefaultProfile $AzureContext).Identity.UserAssignedIdentities.Values.PrincipalId.Contains($identity.PrincipalId))
            {
                $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity.ClientId).context

                # set and store context
                $AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
            }
        else {
                Write-Output "Invalid or unassigned user-assigned managed identity"
                exit
            }
    }
else {
        Write-Output "Invalid method. Choose UA or SA."
        exit
     }

# Get current state of VM
$status = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $VMName `
    -Status -DefaultProfile $AzureContext).Statuses[1].Code

Write-Output "`r`n Beginning VM status: $status `r`n"

# Start or stop VM based on current state
if($status -eq "Powerstate/deallocated")
    {
        Start-AzVM -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
    }
elseif ($status -eq "Powerstate/running")
    {
        Stop-AzVM -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -DefaultProfile $AzureContext -Force
    }

# Get new state of VM
$status = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $VMName -Status `
    -DefaultProfile $AzureContext).Statuses[1].Code  

Write-Output "`r`n Ending VM status: $status `r`n `r`n"

Write-Output "Account ID of current context: " $AzureContext.Account.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine, Below statements are based on the analysis.

In our local environment, We have created a **Powershell runbook** running with different PowerShell Versions 7.1 & Version 5.1.

- Using the above share Script & webhook URI, when we are trying to invoke the runbook (PowerShell version 7.1)  using the `Invoke-webRequest method it is continuously failing.

Alternatively, We have tried to invoke the runbook (PowerShell version 5.1)  using the `Invoke-webRequest` method it is working fine.

**We would suggest you to use Powershell Version 5.1 instead of 7.1 in your Runbook.**

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: I can confirm it works in Powershell 5.1. Do you have any information as to why it doesn't work in Powershell 7?